# Does the session timeout parameter kill object or does the object remain in memory?

Tags: java, session-cookies, session-timeout

in my java project web.xml, session timeout parameter set 5 minutes. After 5 minutes, all session object kill or it remains memory?

Comment: This is a bit more complicated than GC. It has to do with the whole session management process of servlet containers. I'm reopening, because that duplicate did not cover everything.

Comment: As @SotiriosDelimanolis already said, that's a bit more complicated and since I'm no expert on servlet containers (and different containers may choose to handle it differently) I can only guess: when after 5 minutes _of inactivity_ the container invalidates the session it _might_ also be deleted from the container's session store. If there are no other references to the session which prevent GC it _might_ be collected right then, _if_ the garbage collector is run at that moment.

Comment: The contract of [`setMaxInactiveInterval()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval%28int%29) says that it will be invalidated. The question is IMO if `invalidate()` will make the session eligible for GC which is IMO the major purpose of `invalidate()`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question once so I checked out tomcat source code. I did not check everything but I will as much as i did. There is a [StandardSession](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/session/StandardSession.java) class which has many method tow of the methods are related to this.

- one of them is `expire()` which updates isValid variable to false.
- there is another method `recycle()` which clears all attributes and reset many properties like `lastAccessedTime`, `maxInactiveInterval`  etc.

Now I assume that these methods are being called when the session is timed out. So it does not kill them it recycles them.

I went into session manager [ManagerBase](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/4a1399c2be467dd729844632f9b158618432e79e/java/org/apache/catalina/session/ManagerBase.java) to see if that it what it does. Whenever new request comes the the below method is being called(there are few other method calls before this).

```
/**
 * Get a session from the recycled ones or create a new empty one.
 * The PersistentManager manager does not need to create session data
 * because it reads it from the Store.
 */
@Override
public Session createEmptySession() {
    return (getNewSession());
}
```

Comment: i use java struts framework and program listed data and this arraylist set session.setAttribute("dataList" dataList) for example. Garbage collection may be full and server is stop sometimes. I said, perhaps JVM or Weblogic app server still remain memory.We have 300 user and they are listed this list. And list always set to session. Sessions are removed with session.removeAttribute("dataList"). But in my opinion, session can't be kill or remove?

Comment: removeAttribute has nothing to do with killing session. you are just removing that property from the session. what do you mean by server is stop sometime?

Comment: JVM or Weblogic's RAM and CPU level %100 of server and server is stopping. But i fix it. session timeout sets 5 minutes. Now i fix it.Maybe in future, i have to configure heap size or what else..